# Firebase Auth Not working & Completely Unreliable for the past few days

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

The following was working perfectly for months.
The code has recently started to break for the past few days without any changes on app side. Most probably Firebase broke something on their end and already logged in users have started to throw the following errors.

Firebase support is completely unresponsive, so asking it here.
Anybody still stuck on Firebase Please Help.

**Code Used:**

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user == null && !OAuth2Utilities.isBlocked(context)){               
            OAuth2Utilities.initAnonymousFirebaseAccount(context.getApplicationContext());
            return null;
        }
        String userId = user.getUid();
        Task<GetTokenResult> z1 = user.getToken(false);//true means it force refreshes the token, false means will update only if expired-- token by default expires in an hour
        try {
            Tasks.await(z1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String z2 = z1.getResult().getToken();
```

**Error Message:**

`W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at *private*.OAuth2Utilities.getFundaForOAuth2(OAuth2Utilities.java:52)
W/System.err:     at *private*.AsyncTask.PostFetchAsyncTask.doInBackground(PostFetchAsyncTask.java:60)
W/System.err:     at *private*.AsyncTask.PostFetchAsyncTask.doInBackground(PostFetchAsyncTask.java:48)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzago.zzew(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagl$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagw.zzex(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagw$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagr$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)`

Comment: Did you read the error message? `The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again. `

Comment: Yeah, But this issue shouldn't come, since the user is already logged in for almost a 1+ day. Plus the thing was working for everyone before, without any app side changes.

Answer (score 1):

If the same app is working for everyone except a specific user, it is possible that that user changed password or reset the password since last login, and Firebase Authentication requires the user to re-login for security reason.

Since [FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) was thrown from `user.getToken()`, your app should ask the user to login again.

Comment: No, Its happening with me as well, and I did try re-login, it continues to throw the same issue.